# JavaFX - Communication between button and textfield in different controllers doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I got a problem with my desktop app (clinic), here is RegistrationController, which is responsible for entering data about patient, and after click the button "add" - these data will transfer to another controller, which is called InfoPatientController (with FXML file, which displays entered info about patient), for test I set that after click "add" in other window appear text "asdf", but It doesn't work, here is a code and screens:

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
- these error appears

I create MainController but I don't know how could I manage all controllers in one class. Is it possible to manage it in my way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDYRw.jpg

here is RegistrationPatientController:

```
public class RegistrationPatientController implements Initializable {

@FXML
Button registrationButton, infopatientButton, checkoutButton, medicalstaffButton, usersButton, logoutButton,
        exitButton;

@FXML
TextField PIDField, nameField, lastNameField, genderField, ageField, phonenumberField, adressField, diseaseField,
        IDField, dataField, conditionField, priceField;

@FXML
RadioButton normalRoom, vipRoom;

@FXML
MenuButton roomMenuField;

@FXML
MenuItem room101, room102, room103, room104, room105, room106, room107, room108;

@FXML
Button confirmButton, closeButton, addpatientButton;

ToggleGroup choiceRoom = new ToggleGroup();

@FXML
InfoPatientController infoPatientController;

Stage stage;
BorderPane root;

boolean start = true;

String name;
String lastname;
String gender;
String age;
String phonenumber;
String adress;
String disease;
String condition;
String roomtype;

@FXML
public void enterInfoAboutPatient(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
public void roomChoiceAndCalculatePrice(ActionEvent event) {

    normalRoom.setToggleGroup(choiceRoom);
    vipRoom.setToggleGroup(choiceRoom);
    if (choiceRoom.equals(normalRoom)) {
        normalRoom.isSelected();

    }
    if (choiceRoom.equals(vipRoom)) {
        vipRoom.isSelected();
    }

}

@FXML
public void roomNumberChoice(ActionEvent event) {
    String numberRoom101 = "101";
    String numberRoom102 = "102";
    String numberRoom103 = "103";
    String numberRoom104 = "104";
    String numberRoom105 = "105";
    String numberRoom106 = "106";
    String numberRoom107 = "107";
    String numberRoom108 = "108";
    String firstpriceNormalRoom = "30";
    String secondpriceNormalRoom = "40";
    String firstpriceVipRoom = "80";
    String secondpriceVipRoom = "120";

    if (normalRoom.isSelected()) {
        if (event.getSource() == room101) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom101);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room102) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom102);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room103) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom103);
            priceField.setText(secondpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room104) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom104);
            priceField.setText(secondpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room105) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom105);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room106) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom106);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room107) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom107);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room108) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom108);
            priceField.setText(secondpriceNormalRoom);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (vipRoom.isSelected()) {
        if (event.getSource() == room101) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom101);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room102) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom102);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room103) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom103);
            priceField.setText(secondpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room104) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom104);
            priceField.setText(secondpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room105) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom105);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room106) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom106);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room107) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom107);
            priceField.setText(firstpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

        if (event.getSource() == room108) {
            roomMenuField.setText(numberRoom108);
            priceField.setText(secondpriceVipRoom);
            return;
        }

    }

}

@FXML
public void handleAddPatient(ActionEvent event) {

    // name = nameField.getText();
    // lastname = lastNameField.getText();
    // gender = genderField.getText();
    // age = ageField.getText();
    // phonenumber = phonenumberField.getText();
    // adress = adressField.getText();
    // disease = diseaseField.getText();
    // condition = conditionField.getText();

    infoPatientController.infoageField.setText("asdf");

    // boolean enterCondition = !nameField.getText().isEmpty() &&
    // !lastNameField.getText().isEmpty()
    /// && !genderField.getText().isEmpty() && !ageField.getText().isEmpty()
    // && !phonenumberField.getText().isEmpty() &&
    // !adressField.getText().isEmpty()
    // && !diseaseField.getText().isEmpty() &&
    // !conditionField.getText().isEmpty()
    // && (normalRoom.isSelected() || vipRoom.isSelected());
    //
    // boolean choiceRoomCondition = (event.getSource() == room101) ||
    // (event.getSource() == room102)
    // || (event.getSource() == room103) || (event.getSource() == room104)
    // || (event.getSource() == room105)
    // || (event.getSource() == room106) || (event.getSource() == room107)
    // || (event.getSource() == room108);

    // if(enterCondition&choiceRoomCondition)
    // {
    // EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =
    // Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    // EntityManager entityManager =
    // entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    // Patient patient = new Patient();
    // patient.setID(001);
    // patient.setFirstName(name);
    // patient.setLastName(lastname);
    // patient.setGender(gender);
    // patient.setAge(age);
    // patient.setPhonenumber(phonenumber);
    // patient.setAdress(adress);
    // patient.setDisease(disease);
    // patient.setCondition(condition);

    // entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    // entityManager.persist(patient);
    // entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    //
    // entityManager.close();
    // entityManagerFactory.close();
    // }

}

@FXML
public void closeRegistration(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Main.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) registrationButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
    stage.show();
}

@FXML
public void chooseOption(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    if (event.getSource() == registrationButton) {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/RegistrationPatient.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) registrationButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
        stage.show();
        return;
    }

    if (event.getSource() == infopatientButton) {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/InfoPatient.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) infopatientButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
        stage.show();
        return;
    }

    if (event.getSource() == checkoutButton) {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/CheckOutPatient.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) checkoutButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
        stage.show();
        return;
    }

    if (event.getSource() == medicalstaffButton) {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/MedicalStaff.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) medicalstaffButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
        stage.show();
        return;
    }

    if (event.getSource() == usersButton) {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Users.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) usersButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
        stage.show();
        return;
    }

    if (event.getSource() == infopatientButton) {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/InfoPatient.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) infopatientButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
        stage.show();
        return;
    }

    if (event.getSource() == logoutButton) {
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Login.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage) logoutButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 280, 280));
        stage.show();
        return;
    }

    if (event.getSource() == exitButton) {
        stage = (Stage) exitButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    PIDField.setEditable(false);
    dataField.setEditable(false);
    IDField.setEditable(false);
    priceField.setEditable(false);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date = new Date();
    dataField.setText((dateFormat.format(date)));

}
```

}
here is InfoPatientController:

```
public class InfoPatientController implements Initializable {

@FXML
Button registrationButton, infopatientButton, checkoutButton, medicalstaffButton, usersButton,
logoutButton, exitButton;

@FXML
TextField infoPIDField, infonameField, infolastNameField, infogenderField, infoageField,
infophonenumberField, infoadressField, infodiseaseField, infoconditionField, infodataField,
infoRoomNumber, infoRoomType;

@FXML
ListView<String> patientList;

@FXML
Button confirmButton, editButton, closeButton;


@FXML
RegistrationPatientController registrationPatientController;

Stage stage;
BorderPane root;    

boolean start = true;

private MainController main;



  @FXML
  public void enteredInfoAboutPatient(ActionEvent event)
 {

 }

 @FXML
 public void optionsAction(ActionEvent event)
 {

 }

@FXML
public void chooseOption(ActionEvent event) throws IOException 
{

    if(event.getSource()==registrationButton)
    {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/RegistrationPatient.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) registrationButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
    stage.show();
    return;
    }


    if (event.getSource()==infopatientButton)
    {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/InfoPatient.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) infopatientButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
    stage.show();
    return;
    }

    if(event.getSource()==checkoutButton)
    {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/CheckOutPatient.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) checkoutButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
    stage.show();
    return;
    }


    if (event.getSource()==medicalstaffButton)
    {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/MedicalStaff.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) medicalstaffButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
    stage.show();
    return;
    }

    if(event.getSource()==usersButton)
    {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Users.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) usersButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
    stage.show();
    return;
    }


    if (event.getSource()==infopatientButton)
    {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/InfoPatient.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) infopatientButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 530));
    stage.show();
    return;
    }

    if(event.getSource()==logoutButton)
    {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/Login.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) logoutButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.setTitle("Przychodnia");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 280, 280));
    stage.show();
    return;
    }


    if (event.getSource()==exitButton)
    {
    stage = (Stage) exitButton.getScene().getWindow();
    stage.close();
    }
 }

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {



 }
```

Here is error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at 
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at         controller.RegistrationPatientController.handleAddPatient(RegistrationPatientController.java:221)
... 58 more
```

Line nr 221 in RegistrationController:

```
infoPatientController.infoageField.setText("asdf");
```

Here is RegistrationPatient.FXML:

```
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="controller.RegistrationPatientController">
  <center>
     <Pane prefHeight="530.0" prefWidth="750.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
       <children>
         <VBox layoutX="-1.0" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="112.0" />
          <ImageView fitHeight="539.0" fitWidth="953.0" layoutX="-196.0" layoutY="-4.0">
           <image>
              <Image url="@../../../../../Users/Damian/Desktop/asdffff.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
        <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#89a1b9" height="540.0" layoutX="-6.0" layoutY="-3.0" opacity="0.94" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="154.0" />
         <Button fx:id="registrationButton" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="72.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseOption" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="137.0" style="-fx-background-color: #89a1b9; -fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="Zarejestruj pacjenta">
           <cursor>
              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
           </cursor>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="infopatientButton" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="122.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseOption" style="-fx-background-color: #89a1b9; -fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="Informacje o pacjencie">
           <cursor>
              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
           </cursor>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="checkoutButton" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="172.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseOption" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="137.0" style="-fx-background-color: #89a1b9; -fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="Wypisz pacjenta">
           <cursor>
              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
           </cursor>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="medicalstaffButton" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="225.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseOption" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="137.0" style="-fx-background-color: #89a1b9; -fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="Personel medyczny">
           <cursor>
              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
           </cursor>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="usersButton" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="275.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseOption" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="137.0" style="-fx-background-color: #89a1b9; -fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="Użytkownicy">
           <cursor>
              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
           </cursor>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="logoutButton" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseOption" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="64.0" style="-fx-background-color: #89a1b9; -fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="Wyloguj">
           <cursor>
              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
           </cursor>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="78.0" layoutY="325.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseOption" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="63.0" style="-fx-background-color: #89a1b9; -fx-border-color: WHITE;" text="Zamknij">
           <cursor>
              <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
           </cursor>
        </Button>
        <ImageView fitHeight="200.0" fitWidth="200.0" layoutX="550.0" layoutY="350.0">
           <image>
              <Image url="@../../../../../Users/Damian/Desktop/imagesff.png" />
           </image>
        </ImageView>
        <Label layoutX="36.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="37.0" prefWidth="489.0" text="MENU" wrapText="true">
           <font>
              <Font size="28.0" />
           </font>
        </Label>
        <Pane layoutX="164.0" layoutY="17.0" opacity="0.85" prefHeight="497.0" prefWidth="572.0" style="-fx-background-color: #81a1b9;">
           <children>
              <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#95b1cc00" height="98.0" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="10.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="189.0" />
              <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#95b1cc00" height="369.0" layoutX="5.0" layoutY="109.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="349.0" />
              <Label layoutX="25.0" layoutY="15.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="90.0" text="ID rejestracji">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="41.0" text="ID:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="78.0" text="Data:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="25.0" layoutY="124.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="143.0" text="Informacje o pacjencie">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="150.0" text="PID:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="186.0" text="Imię:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="227.0" text="Nazwisko:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="265.0" text="Płeć:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="11.0" layoutY="305.0" text="Wiek:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="342.0" text="Telefon:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="382.0" text="Adres:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="419.0" text="Dolegliwość:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#95b1cc00" height="98.0" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="10.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="156.0" />
              <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#95b1cc00" height="477.0" layoutX="363.0" layoutY="10.0" stroke="WHITE" strokeType="INSIDE" width="202.0" />
              <Label layoutX="216.0" layoutY="15.0" text="Rodzaj pokoju">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <RadioButton fx:id="normalRoom" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="40.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomChoiceAndCalculatePrice" text="Zwykły">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </RadioButton>
              <RadioButton fx:id="vipRoom" layoutX="217.0" layoutY="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomChoiceAndCalculatePrice" text="VIP">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="14.0" />
                 </font>
              </RadioButton>
              <Label layoutX="374.0" layoutY="15.0" text="Informacje o pokoju pacjenta">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="375.0" layoutY="55.0" text="Numer pokoju:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <Label layoutX="375.0" layoutY="99.0" text="Cena:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <TextField fx:id="PIDField" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="148.0" />
              <TextField fx:id="nameField" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="184.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" />
              <TextField fx:id="lastNameField" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="224.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" />
              <TextField fx:id="genderField" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="263.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" />
              <TextField fx:id="ageField" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="303.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
              <TextField fx:id="phonenumberField" layoutX="175.0" layoutY="340.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="149.0" />
              <TextField fx:id="adressField" layoutX="59.0" layoutY="380.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="267.0" />
              <TextField fx:id="diseaseField" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="416.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" />
              <TextField fx:id="IDField" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="39.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="121.0" />
              <TextField fx:id="dataField" layoutX="69.0" layoutY="76.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="121.0" />
              <MenuButton fx:id="roomMenuField" layoutX="471.0" layoutY="52.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="87.0">
                <items>
                  <MenuItem fx:id="room101" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="101" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="room102" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="102" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="room103" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="103" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="room104" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="104" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="room105" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="105" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="room106" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="106" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="room107" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="107" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="room108" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" text="108" />
                </items>
              </MenuButton>
              <TextField fx:id="priceField" layoutX="472.0" layoutY="96.0" onAction="#roomNumberChoice" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="85.0" />
              <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="448.0" text="Stan pacjenta:">
                 <font>
                    <Font size="13.0" />
                 </font>
              </Label>
              <TextField fx:id="conditionField" layoutX="177.0" layoutY="445.0" onAction="#enterInfoAboutPatient" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="147.0" />
              <Button fx:id="closeButton" layoutX="422.0" layoutY="258.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeRegistration" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Zamknij" />
              <Button fx:id="addpatientButton" layoutX="421.0" layoutY="197.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAddPatient" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Dodaj" />
           </children></Pane>
     </children>
     </Pane>
  </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace and identify the line at which it occurs.

Comment: Ok I paste it, I guess, not sure if I did what you ask for

Comment: So either `infoPatientController` or `infoPatientController.infoageField` is null. How is `infoPatientController` injected into the `RegistrationController`?  Are you using `<fx:include>` in the FXML?

Comment: Exactly It's not injected in any way, in which line I should inject <fx:include> ? Will it work then? I paste in post FXML file for RegistrationPatientController